# prototype inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript

I took the following example from the book *Javascript Good Parts* and I ran it in firefox:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, value){
    this.prototype[name] = value;
    return this;
}

Number.method('integer', function (  ) {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
});

console.log((-10 / 3).integer());
```

This is my understand of how it works. We use the () high precedence operator to evaluate -10/3, which gives this 64-bit floating point value -3.3... Since JavaScript has not Float, Decimal, or Integer types, the return value is Number. Hence, we call the function integer() on Number object, which is in its prototype chain. "this" must refer to the value the Number object holds. We use ternary to check if its negative or positive and in this case we run: Math'ceil' since it was negative. This will round the number upward to produce -3.

This script will work, but what I don't understand is why Number.method doesn't throw an exception, since Number is not a type of Function and method was defined on Function's prototype, not Number's prototype and Number doesn't inherit from Function, it only inherits from Object.prototype.

Comment: It is an instanceof Function: `Number instanceof Function === true`

Comment: @PatrickEvans then why does Number lack the execution ability? ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try these examples out in your console**

`Number` is a function.

```
typeof Number
"function"
```

confirms that.

As such, `Number` does inherit from `Function`

```
Number instanceOf Function
"true"
```

And `Function`, like all other JavaScript objects, inherits from `Object`

```
Function instanceof Object
true
```

Comment: Then how come Number cannot be executed like a function?

Comment: it can be executed like a function: `var num = Number(13);`

Comment: @PatrickEvans so what's the purpose of Object.prototype and Object itself when everything already inherits from Function?

Comment: Everything does not inherit from Function, everything inherits from Object. For instance: `"string" instanceof Function === false`

Comment: @JohnMerlino Not everything inherits from Function!  There are lots and lots of JavaScript objects that aren't functions.

Comment: I see, just to note that the String object itself is a typeof and instance of Function: String instanceof Function. But a string literal such as "string" is not. Hence, we can actually call method too on String: String.method and it will work.